# Python Tkinterprogramm import to a new file throws a error

Tags: python, tkinter, import

i have a problem with the user-output of my tkinter gui.
First of all it works, but there is a huge problem with the import to a new py file. It throws a Error ().

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python_Projekt\Übung\Plus\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    tk = own.get_start()
  File "F:\Python_Projekt\Übung\Plus\plus_window_pack2.py", line 31, in get_start
    sel = ListBox1.curselection()
  File "C:\Users\nox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2782, in curselection
    return self._getints(self.tk.call(self._w, 'curselection')) or ()
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!frame.!listbox"
```

I know there is a problem with my ListBox but i have no clue how to handle it. I need the used output for my new script. So i could work with it.

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk

window = Tk()
rahmen1 = Frame(master = window) #, bg='black'
rahmen1.pack(side='top', padx=5, pady=5)
rahmen2 = Frame(master = rahmen1)  #, bg= 'yellow'
rahmen2.pack(side='left', padx=5, pady=5)


def get_start():
    selection=ListBox1.curselection()
    picked = selection[0]
    used = ListBox1.get(picked)              #-------user-input
    print(used)
    return used

####################----------------------------------------------------


List = ['Dax','Dow','EUR/USD', 'Gold', 'Silber','EUR/JPY','USD/JPY']

scrollbar1 = Scrollbar(rahmen2) # ,bg='green'
scrollbar1.pack(padx = 1,side = 'right',fill=Y)

ListBox1 = Listbox(rahmen2,exportselection = False)
ListBox1.config( yscrollcommand = scrollbar1.set, width = 40)
scrollbar1.config( command = ListBox1.yview) # ,bg='blue'
for i in List:
    ListBox1.insert(tk.END, str(i))
ListBox1.pack(padx = 1,)


###################------------------------------------------------

Button1 = Button(rahmen2,text='Get Data', font = 'bold')
Button1.config (width=40, height = 3, command = get_start)
Button1.pack( )


window.mainloop()
```

I changed the code to get the important part. For a better understanding of my problem.
if i want to get the user-input it thorw's me the error.

Comment: The error implies that the listbox has been destroyed.

Comment: What is `ListBox1`?

Comment: Please provide [mcve] as opposed to a piece of your code. We shouldn't be guessing your code, [so] is rather about deterministic help.

Comment: I added some more informations. If you need more pls tell me im quite new

Comment: I changed the whole code for the important part

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have added a simple check to make sure something's selected (I'm not sure what the error at the top of your question's about though):

```
def get_start():
    selection=ListBox1.curselection()
    if len (selection) != 0:
        picked = selection[0]
        used = ListBox1.get(picked)              #-------user-input
        print(used)
        return used
```

EDIT:
This checks every `x` seconds (defined by `UPDATE_TIME`) for checkbox updates

```
UPDATE_TIME = 0.1


from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
import threading, time

window = Tk()
rahmen1 = Frame(master = window) #, bg='black'
rahmen1.pack(side='top', padx=5, pady=5)
rahmen2 = Frame(master = rahmen1)  #, bg= 'yellow'
rahmen2.pack(side='left', padx=5, pady=5)


def get_start():
    print (previous)
    return previous
def get_update ():
    global previous
    try:
        while True:
            selection=ListBox1.curselection()
            if len (selection) == 0: previous = None
            else:
                picked = selection[0]
                previous = ListBox1.get(picked)              #-------user-input
            time.sleep (UPDATE_TIME)
    except: pass

####################----------------------------------------------------


List = ['Dax','Dow','EUR/USD', 'Gold', 'Silber','EUR/JPY','USD/JPY']

scrollbar1 = Scrollbar(rahmen2) # ,bg='green'
scrollbar1.pack(padx = 1,side = 'right',fill=Y)

ListBox1 = Listbox(rahmen2,exportselection = False)
ListBox1.config( yscrollcommand = scrollbar1.set, width = 40)
scrollbar1.config( command = ListBox1.yview) # ,bg='blue'
for i in List:
    ListBox1.insert(tk.END, str(i))
ListBox1.pack(padx = 1,)


###################------------------------------------------------

Button1 = Button(rahmen2,text='Get Data', font = 'bold')
Button1.config (width=40, height = 3, command = get_start)
Button1.pack ()

threading.Thread (target = get_update).start ()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: still the same problem try to open the module with a import test_window  and check if you can use the used output. thats my problem.

Comment: I have tried importing your code from another program as `test_window.py` but it works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would make a difference but could it be your path names?

Comment: ok try someother thing if you import it store the get_start function in a variable and try to acces the used output. Maybe thats a betetr explanation. Thx

Comment: I think that is what i should write before :D The path names are fine

Comment: You are trying to get a value from the listbox after the window has been closed. This is problematic as Tkinter forgets the widgets after window closure.

Comment: hmm thats a real problem. Do you have any solution or is it impossible to store the imput for a later access. Maybe i store it in a text file or something?

Comment: Please try my updated code (note: be careful with threading!).

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to get it to call a method when there is a change in selection

Comment: i not quite understand why it works but i will check it later on. I even dont know what the threading do. Thanks for edit. Selection is 0 if there is no highlighted option right?

Comment: You are right about the selection thing. Threading just activates the set method to run SIMULTANEOUSLY to the main code.